# Get the logging level in spring boot application

Tags: java, spring-boot, logging

I have created a `Benchmark` annotation that gives the execution time of a method call using `Stopwatch`. The `Benchmark` annotation has an attribute `isEnabled` which is `true` by default. What I want is that even if the value if set to `false` for some method, if the logging level is `DEBUG`, the benchmarking be done. Is there a way in spring boot to get the current logging level of the application. I am aware that we can have multiple logging levels enabled for different packages. If for the current package or module, the logging level is set to DEBUG, the benchmark should be executed. This is how my `Benchmark` annotation looks like:

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
public @interface Benchmark {

    boolean isEnabled() default true;
}
```

The aspect that does the benchmarking looks like this:

```
@Aspect
@Component
public class BenchmarkingAspect {

    @Around("@annotation(benchmark)")
    public Object benchmarkMethodRuntimeAspect(ProceedingJoinPoint proceedingJoinPoint, Benchmark benchmark) throws Throwable {
        if (benchmark.isEnabled()) {
            StopWatch stopWatch = new StopWatch();
            stopWatch.start();
            Object returnedValue = proceedingJoinPoint.proceed();
            stopWatch.stop();
            log.info("Benchmarked: {} from class {}", proceedingJoinPoint.getSignature().getName(),
                    proceedingJoinPoint.getTarget().getClass().getCanonicalName());
            log.info(stopWatch.prettyPrint());
            return returnedValue;
        } else {
            return proceedingJoinPoint.proceed();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can just do;

```
Logger targetLogger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(proceedingJoinPoint.getTarget().getClass())
if (targetLog.isDebugEnabled()) {
    // apply your logic here
}
```